# Use preceding \K group negatively

Tags: ruby, regex

Can I use the the preceding \K group negatively? Can I match the `bar` inside `faxbar` `funbar` `bobar` and `bar` and omit the bar inside `foobar` `fobar` `foooooobar`? https://regex101.com/r/qR9kD4/5

Regex

```
fo*\Kbar
```

String: (- and desired outcome)

```
foobar       - no match
fobar        - no match
foooooobar   - no match
faxbar       - match 'bar'
funbar       - match 'bar'
bobar        - match 'bar'
bar          - match 'bar'
dontmineidontwanttfooooobematchedaatall  - no match
```

Basically invert my current matches (apart from `dontmineme...`). Hoping I just need to add a `!` or something!

Comment: Use positive look-ahead `(?=)`

Comment: nhahtdh isn't your name the final boss in Half Life 1? Anyway, how do I use a look-ahead without any pattern to 'grab onto'?

Comment: Now that the question is cleared up, my comment won't work. It should be possible if you can filter the matches, but not sure if there is a way to do so without.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\K` with a Negative Lookahead assertion:

```
\b(?!fo+)\w*\Kbar
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/dP9fM7/2)

A simple solution would be to place what you want to ignore on the left side of the alternation and place what you want to match in a capturing group on the right side of the alternation operator.

```
fo+bar|\w*(bar)
```

Comment: How would the first be used? For excample, `'fobar' =~ /fo*bar|\w*\K(bar)/] #=> 0`. (Same with `/fo+bar.../`.)

Comment: Your second regex passes the test in my answer. Your first regex fails the first three tests and passes the others.  I changed the last line to `].each { |str,result| puts (!!(str =~ R) == result) }` and set `R` equal to your regex.

Comment: @hwnd this more understanding then anything...but why is it that white space is being ignored by my negative lookahead https://regex101.com/r/dP9fM7/3 ? that second line shouldn't be matched?

Answer (score 2):

If you can use anchors, it may be doable.  They enable you to make sure the `bar` you peek at in the lookahead is same `bar` you consume in the main regex:

```
^(?!fo+bar$)[a-z]*\Kbar$

\b(?!fo+bar\b)[a-z]*\Kbar\b
```

If you can't use anchors, it may not be possible.  We would need to know a lot more about the kind of strings you're expecting to see, as well as more detailed criteria for matching them.

But I have to ask, do you really have to use `\K`?  Lookarounds may seem like the obvious approach, but it's often much easier to use capturing groups.

```
\b(?!fo+bar\b)[a-z]*(bar)\b
```

You just use `$~[1]` instead of `$&` to extract the substring you're interested in.

Comment: All pass the test in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
R = /^fo|bar/
str[R]=='bar'
```

though it doesn't use `\K`.

```
[
  ['foobar',                                  false],
  ['fobar',                                   false],
  ['foooooobar',                              false],
  ['faxbar',                                  true ],
  ['funbar',                                  true ],
  ['bobar',                                   true ],
  ['bar',                                     true ],
  ['dontmineidontwanttfooooobematchedaatall', false],
].each { |str,result| (str[R]=='bar') == result }
true
true
...
true
```

Others offering answers may want to use my test code.